# Are deities from classic mythology free to use?

Tags: copyright

For instance the deities (or gods) from Japanese, Roman, Greek, Hindu etc. mythologies. Can they be used in modern times without authorization from any copyright holders?

Comment: Up till now, yes. Perhaps one day they will be privatized, then this might change. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear to me how you "use" a mythological entity, and I take no position as to the divine consequences of any unauthorized uses, but you are entitled to incorporate then in your own intellectual creations for two reasons. First, any imaginable copyright on original texts (e.g. the Bhagavad Gita) has long since expired. Not all texts are of such certifiably ancient provenance, so there may be contemporary texts created by a practitioner of Ásatrúarfélagið which is protected. Second, names (Amitāyus, Zaraθuštra, Ngai) are not protected by copyright, so you can use names.

Comment: ..has long since expired or was never in place anyway. Copyright was not granted retroactively.

Comment: copyright can be held on translations of ancient text. Every Bible is copyrighted by the organisations who commisioned the translation. Although such text like the KJV can also fall in the public domain.

Comment: If you use names like "Thor" and "Loki" you might run into someone's trademarks. If you do, ask your lawyer if you can post the outcome here.